# Configuration issue for smaller screen size

Tags: html, css, media-queries

The picture on the left is what it looks like now on a phone screen. The picture on the right is what I'd like it to look like, where more words can fit per line. I made the html background red to highlight it and the body div in grey.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP9m5.png)

What changes would I need to make to the code in order to get that result? I'm not sure why the page includes that part on the right side, but the left side looks okay. I'd like to get that part off the screen. I'm not sure if this piece of code helps, but here it is: (maybe it has to do with the `div.container`)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
        div.container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: auto !important;
    }
```

Comment: Check the `right-padding` or `max-width` rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these in your style :

```
html,body{
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

if it doesn't make any sense, then add this viewport to your head tag in html :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

Comment: I tried both, and no luck. When I change the width of the screen on my laptop, it works smoothly. But when I view the site on my phone, that html space is there. Maybe the code "thinks" the screen size is smaller than the actual phone size?

Comment: @Alexander if u give me the online link then I can help you well !

Comment: '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />' An addition to your suggestion and modifying some margins in the body did the trick. Thanks for your help! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Alexander glad to hear ! don't forget the ✓